# Template function for a class object

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Apologies for not being able to post any code for this problem as i am very new to C++.

I Have a Class

```
class Container
{
  private:
   std::string stdstrContainerName;
   std::string stdstrPluginType;
   int iSegments;
   float fRadius;

public:
   Container();
   Container(std::string , std::string ,  int , float);
   Container(const  Container& obj);    
   ~Container();
   std::string GetName();
   std::string GetType();
   void SetName(std::string stdstrName);
};
```

I want to change the parameter of the class object using a function.

```
  void ChangeParameter( Container cont , std::string strParameterName , 
  value( "which can be either string or int" ));


 Void Container::Set(  std::string strParamValue ,  std:string  Value)
  {
    if( strParamValue == "stdstrContainerName" )
     stdstrContainerName = Value;

    if( strParamValue == "stdstrPluginType" )
    stdstrPluginType = Value;
  }
```

Can i have a function where i dont have to use if conditions

Comment: you dont need templates. You simply want a `void ChangeParameter( Container, std::string,string);` and a `void ChangeParameter( Container, std::string,int);`

Comment: Thanks that is what i have done currently but my container class is quite big with lot of different variables so i though instead of multiple overloaded function , if i can use one function only.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? It sounds like a design you could use in an interpreted language, but not suited for c++.

Comment: Thanks this clears my doubt about the best way forward.

Comment: templates do not help you if you need to do something different for each type. You would have to specialize for each type and then assign to the respective member, ie you just make it look like a generic template but in the back it still is nothing more than one overload for each member you want to assign to

Comment: One more thing currently i am using if condition to change the data, is this the right way , adding more code to the current code.

Comment: Maybe write what you actually want to achieve, that is in particular in what context you need what. From what you write, it sounds as if simply overloading your function would do what you want.

Comment: Please see the new code can i avoid IF statements.

Comment: Don't you just want individual setters? `SetContainerName(string name);`, `SetPluginType(string type);`, `Set...` for each, etc.

Comment: sure that works but i thought if i could have something generic.

Comment: Generic in what way? A specific setter would be robust towards errors. If on the other hand you use strings, mistyping would produce a run-time error but no compile error. But if you really need to do something like that, store the data in a `std::map<std::string,std::string>`. But again, us knowing for what you need all of that would be quite useful.

Comment: The `SetName(string,string)` function defines an interface what takes two strings. If this interface should be kept, you could consider a `std::hash_map<string,string> AllData` member. The constructor can add all possible members to `AddData`, the SetName function can check if `strParamValue` is found in that `AllData` hash_map. If found, it can replace it. Similar `GetName` tries to get the corresponding `name` value from the hash_map `AllData`.